# Is there a way in which I can render shop products on the frontend in React-router-dom V6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, redux, react-router-dom

I am building an E-commerce web-app in which only shops create products. each product belongs to a shop and each shop has it's own products. Thus, when I tap on a shop, It takes me to a page with products specifically for that shop. With all I have done, am getting a blank page with undefined internal server error.

here is my shop controller.js

```
const Product = require("../models/product");

const ErrorHandler = require("../utils/errorHandler");
const catchAsyncErrors = require("../middlewares/catchAsyncErrors");
const APIFeatures = require("../utils/apiFeatures");
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary')

const crypto = require("crypto");
const geoCoder = require("../utils/geocoder");


exports.getProductsByShopId = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
 const products = await Product.find({ shop: req.params.shopId });

 res.status(200).json({
   success: true,
   count: products.length,
   products,
 });
});
```

here is my product model

```
   const slugify = require('slugify');

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: {
   type: String,
   required: [true, "Please enter product name"],
   trim: true,
   maxLength: [100, "Product name cannot exceed 100 characters"],
 },

 price: {
   type: Number,
   required: [true, "Please enter product price"],
   maxLength: [20, "Product name cannot exceed 20 characters"],
   default: 0.0,
 },
 description: {
   type: String,
   required: [true, "Please enter product description"],
 },
 ratings: {
   type: Number,
   default: 0,
 },
 images: [
   {
     public_id: {
       type: String,
       required: true,
     },
     url: {
       type: String,
       required: true,
     },
   },
 ],
 seller: {
   type: String,
   required: [true, "Please enter product seller"],
 },
 stock: {
   type: Number,
   required: [true, "Please enter product stock"],
   maxLength: [5, "Product name cannot exceed 5 characters"],
   default: 0,
 },
 numOfReviews: {
   type: Number,
   default: 0,
 },
 reviews: [
   {
     user: {
       type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       required: true,
       ref: "User",
     },
     username: {
       type: String,
       required: true,
     },
     rating: {
       type: Number,
       required: true,
     },
     comment: {
       type: String,
       required: true,
     },
   },
 ],
 shop: {
   type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
   //type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: "Shop",
   required: false,
 },
 user: {
   type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
   //type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: "User",
   required: false,
 },
 createdAt: {
   type: Date,
   default: Date.now,
 },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
```

Beloew is my shop routes

```
const router = express.Router();


const { 


    getProductsByShopId,

} = require('../controllers/shopController');


//SHOP ROUTES

router.route('/shops/:shopId/products').get(getProductsByShopId);

module.exports = router;
```

On the frontend; Here is my shop Reducers page?

```
   SHOP_PRODUCTS_REQUEST,
   SHOP_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
   SHOP_PRODUCTS_FAIL,

   CLEAR_ERRORS,
 } from '../constants/shopConstants';


export const shopProductsReducer = (state = { products: [] }, action ) => {
   switch(action.type) {
       case SHOP_PRODUCTS_REQUEST:
           return {
               ...state,
               loading: true,
               products: []
           }
           
       case SHOP_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
               
           return {
               ...state,
               loading: false,
               products: action.payload,
           } 
              
       case SHOP_PRODUCTS_FAIL:
           return {
               ...state,
               error: null
           }
       case CLEAR_ERRORS:
           return {
               ...state,
               error: null
           }

      default:
       return state 
   }
}
```

Again here is my shop actions

```
import {


   SHOP_PRODUCTS_REQUEST,
   SHOP_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
   SHOP_PRODUCTS_FAIL,

   CLEAR_ERRORS,
 } from '../constants/shopConstants';



export const getProductsByShopId = (shopId) => async (dispatch) => {
   try{

       dispatch({ type: SHOP_PRODUCTS_REQUEST})

       const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/shops/${shopId}/products`)

       dispatch({
           type: SHOP_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
           payload: data,
       })

   } catch (error) {
       dispatch({
           type: SHOP_PRODUCTS_FAIL,
           payload: error.response.data.message
       })
   }
}



 //Clear Errors
 export const clearErrors = () => async (dispatch) => {
   dispatch({
       type: CLEAR_ERRORS
   })
 }
```

Here is the store.js file

```
import { thunk } from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'

import {  shopProductsReducer } from './reducers/shopReducers';
import { productsReducer, productDetailsReducer, } from './reducers/productReducers';

const reducer = combineReducers({
   shopProducts: shopProductsReducer,

})

let initialState = {}

const middleware = [thunk];
const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)))

export default store;
```

My App.js file

```
import Header from "./components/layout/Header";
import Footer from "./components/layout/Footer";
import shopProducts from './components/shop/ShopProducts'
import "./App.css";

function App() {
 return (
   <Router>
     <div className="App">
       <Header />
       <div className="big-container">
       <Routes>
         <Route path="/shops/:shopId/products" element={<ShopProducts />} exact />
       </Routes>

       </div>

       <Footer />
     </div>
   </Router>
 );
}

export default App;
```

Finally, here is the page on which i want to render products belonging to the shop.

```
import Loader from '../layout/Loader';
import MetaData from '../layout/MetaData';
import { useAlert } from 'react-alert';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import {  getProductsByShopId, clearErrors } from '../../actions/shopActions';

const ShopProducts = ({shopId}) => {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   const alert = useAlert();
   const params = useParams();

   const { loading, error,  products  } = useSelector(
       (state) => state.shopProducts
     );

   useEffect(() => {
       dispatch(getProductsByShopId(shopId));
       if (error) {
           alert.error(error);
           dispatch(clearErrors());
         }

   }, [dispatch, alert, error, shopId])
 return (
   <Fragment>
   {loading ? <Loader /> : (
       <Fragment>
       <div className='container wigdy'>
       <h1 className='heading'>Walmart products</h1>
       <div className='box-container pb-5'>
           {products && products.map((product) => (
                           <div className='box'>
                           <img src='/images/718BW18SfUL._AC_SY695_.jpg' />
                           <div className='mawords mb-3'>
                           <a href=''>{product.name}</a> 
                           <p>Ksh {product.price}</p>
                           <a href='' className='baton'>Add to cart</a>
                           </div>
                       </div>
           ))}

       </div>
   </div>
       </Fragment>
   )}
   </Fragment>
 )
}

export default ShopProducts
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the Redux and backend code is correct, the issue I see is with the `ShopProducts` accessing the `shopId` to be used to make the GET request to the backend APIs.

Given the following route declaration:

```
<Route path="/shops/:shopId/products" element={<ShopProducts />} />
```

`shopId` is a route path parameter, not a prop passed to the `ShopProducts` component. Access it via the [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params) hook in the routed component.

```
import { useAlert } from 'react-alert';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Loader from '../layout/Loader';
import MetaData from '../layout/MetaData';
import { getProductsByShopId, clearErrors } from '../../actions/shopActions';

const ShopProducts = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const alert = useAlert();

  const { shopId } = useParams(); // <-- access shopId from params

  const { loading, error,  products } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.shopProducts
  );

  // Fetch shop products when shop id changes
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProductsByShopId(shopId));
  }, [dispatch, shopId]);

  // Check for errors and alert separately
  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      alert.error(error);
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }
  }, [dispatch, alert, error]);

 return loading
   ? <Loader />
   : (
     <div className='container wigdy'>
       <h1 className='heading'>Walmart products</h1>
       <div className='box-container pb-5'>
         {products?.map((product) => (
           <div key={product.id} className='box'>
             <img src='/images/718BW18SfUL._AC_SY695_.jpg' />
             <div className='mawords mb-3'>
               <Link to='.....'>{product.name}</Link>
               <p>Ksh {product.price}</p>
               <Link to='.....' className='baton'>Add to cart</Link>
             </div>
           </div>
         ))}
       </div>
     </div>
   );
};

export default ShopProducts;
```

Comment: after writing your code, the only thing that is rendered on the shopProducts component is the h1 tag Walmart Products.  But surprisingly, the redux store says SHOP_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS. Postman request also returns shop products. What might be the problem?

Comment: @pierre Maybe `action.payload` isn't what you think it is in the `SHOP_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS` reducer case. What is the value of `data` from ```const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/shops/${shopId}/products`)```, e.g. what is the `action.payload` value being processed?

Comment: How do i get the value of data from const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/shops/${shopId}/products`) ?

Comment: @pierre You can console log in right there in the action. You could also inspect the response in the network tab of the browser's dev-tools.

Comment: consol.log(data) returns the shop products {success: true, count: 9, products: Array(9)}....the only challenge is to see them on the shopProducts component page.

Comment: @pierre Try dispatching `data.products`, e.g. `dispatch({ type: SHOP_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS, payload: data.products })`, so the action payload is the products array, ***or*** in the reducer, unpack the products array, e.g. `products: action.payload.products,`.

Comment: even after unpacking data.products, still same issue.  Products show in console and redux store but nothing in shopProducts component.

Comment: @pierre Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: When I console. log(error) I get this in the browser console with a 500 internal server error. Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/v1/shops/65f96e88c40096a98e6df70b/products from localhost:3000 to http://127.0.0.1:4000.   
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).

Comment: @pierre I believe that means your server isn't running, or wherever it is running that *that* host refused the connection. Is this on your local machine or was this when you tried setting up a codesandbox? If in the sandbox you can mock a call to an API and simply return the response object directly. In other words, don't actually try to connect to a server endpoint, just return mock data the endpoint would return. This makes testing easier since won't need any services running anywhere.